# Showing link in menu conditional on logged in status

Tags: django, mezzanine

Using Mezzanine it's easy to toggle showing or not showing of regular pages using the 'Login necessary' toggle.

I want use this toggle for a Link-type page, unfortunately it's not there. What's the best way to achieve the toggling effect in Mezzanine?

I probably can inherit from the Link class and do something like this

```
class LoginLink(Link):
    login_required = models.BooleanField(_("Login required"), default=False,
        help_text=_("If checked, only logged in users can view this page"))
```

and use LoginLink as the page type instead but I hope there is a better solution. A better solution would have the following:

- No new page type
- No messing with core Mezzanine

I'm pretty sure my proposed solution works (but I really don't like it). Is it possible to extend the Mezzanine Link type in such a way only my own Link type is visible in the admin?

Comment: Duplicates aren't the only kind of off-topic question. See the [content on asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in the Help Center.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Is it better like this?

Comment: It's still pretty vague. Did you try your *"something like this"*? What happened? How would you define *"better"*, or *"the best way"* (feels opinion-based)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that's pretty short and sweet. The nice thing is that the login_required is already available for all pages through pages_page so we don't have to do any database modifications. With this solution you lose the option to create the default link type but in my case that's a plus from a usability perspective. One Link type is sufficient. The code for my solutions is as follows and goes into `admin.py`

```
# Get the Mezzannine admin logic and the Link model
from mezzanine.pages.admin import LinkAdmin
from mezzanine.pages.models import Link

# Create a custom LoginLink, with the login_required code from the page.
from copy import deepcopy
class LoginLinkAdmin(LinkAdmin):
    fieldsets = deepcopy(LinkAdmin.fieldsets) + \
             ((None, {"fields": ("login_required",)}),)

# Unregister and register the LinkAdmin
admin.site.unregister(Link)
admin.site.register(Link, LoginLinkAdmin)
```

Adding this should be copy and paste.

## Edit

I later found that this is the preferred way in the [documentation](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/model-customization.html#admin-fields). However, this only seems to work in my dev environment and not in our production-like environment. Further searching led me to the [Model Customization docs](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/model-customization.html). I didn't get this to work but it gave me a new idea. Mezzanine overrides the standard admin.site functionality, as described in this comment in `/mezzanine/boot/lazy_admin.py`:

```
"""
Defers calls to register/unregister until autodiscover is called
to avoid load issues with injectable model fields defined by
``settings.EXTRA_MODEL_FIELDS``.
"""
```

So I've come up with yet another solution. I've put the code above in my `urls.py` after `admin.autodiscover()` and deleted it from `admin.py`. This is ugly but it seems to work.